# How to use "before_save :geocode" without throwing "Google Geocoding API error: over query limit."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocode, rails-geocoder

I am using Ruby Geocoder with Rails.  I have the following in my model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  geocoded_by :locale

  def locale
    [city, state].compact.join(', ')
  end

  before_save :geocode #, :if => :address_changed?
end
```

I have a rake task that imports cities & states into the locations database.  However, as it is running, it throws the following error constantly:

```
Google Geocoding API error: over query limit.
```

The [Geocoder docs](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#bulk-geocoding) offer this option for the rake task to alleviate the problem:

```
rake geocode:all CLASS=YourModel SLEEP=0.25 BATCH=100
```

How would I put an option like that in the `before_save` callback in my model?

Comment: Why can't you just put a sleep statement in your rake task?

Comment: I'm trying to use it automatically in the before_save callback rather than having to manually run a rake task.

Comment: Putting it in the before_save callback means it would sleep anytime you save the model, even when you're saving a single object.  Insert the delay in the place that you are looping over the model objects. That seems to be your rake task that imports the data.